# How can I construct this matrix?

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, linear-algebra

How can I construct this matrix by MMA?

$\left(\begin{array}{cccccc}1 & 2 & 3 & \cdots & n-1 & n \\ n & 1 & 2 & \cdots & n-2 & n-1 \\ n-1 & n & 1 & \cdots & n-3 & n-2 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & & \vdots & \vdots \\ 2 & 3 & 4 & \cdots & n & 1\end{array}\right)$

Comment: Tenfold challenge: completed ✓

Comment: @bmf It's amazing! The answers are all great. I gave the ✓ to the one with the highest vote.

Comment: Good choice. The accept should be either the answer by Roman or kglr. Quite fun reading through all the alternatives. Nice question!

Comment: Cool question: I wrote it down, wil think about this over the night.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
a[n_Integer?Positive] := Array[Mod[#2 - #1, n] + 1 &, {n, n}]

a[6] // MatrixForm
```

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cccccc}
 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
 6 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
 5 & 6 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
 4 & 5 & 6 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 1 & 2 \\
 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Answer (score 16):

Here is an approach (pulling out the length as a sort of parameter--set `len` to whatever you want):

```
With[
  {len=5},
  NestList[RotateRight,Range[len],len-1]]
```

Answer (score 16):

```
tm[n_] := ToeplitzMatrix[RotateRight @ Reverse @ Range @ n, Range @ n] 

TeXForm @ tm[5]
```

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
 5 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
 4 & 5 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
 3 & 4 & 5 & 1 & 2 \\
 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Answer (score 8):

You can use [`SparseArray`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SparseArray.html) and [`Band`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Band.html)

```
sa[n_] :=
 Normal@SparseArray[
   Flatten[
    {Band[{1, 1}] -> 1,
     Table[Band[{1, i}] -> i, {i, 2, n}], 
     Diagonal[
      Table[Table[Band[{k, 1}] -> n - x, {k, 2, n}], {x, 0, 
        n - 2}]]},
    1
    ],
   {n, n}
   ]

Grid@Partition[MatrixForm /@ Table[sa[xx], {xx, 2, 13}], 3]
```

> [image: res]

Answer (score 7):

```
rrmat[n_] := RotateRight[Range[n], #] & /@ Range[0, n - 1]
```

Test:

```
MatrixForm /@ (rrmat /@ Range[2, 6])
```

$$\left\{\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 2 \\
 2 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right),\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 2 & 3 \\
 3 & 1 & 2 \\
 2 & 3 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right),\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
 4 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
 3 & 4 & 1 & 2 \\
 2 & 3 & 4 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right),\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
 5 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
 4 & 5 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
 3 & 4 & 5 & 1 & 2 \\
 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right),\left(
\begin{array}{cccccc}
 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
 6 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
 5 & 6 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
 4 & 5 & 6 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 1 & 2 \\
 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)\right\}$$

Answer (score 7):

Another use of FoldList

```
len = 6; 
FoldList[RotateRight, Range[len], ConstantArray[1, len - 1]]
```

Comment: (+1) and just a related minor comment: @N.J.Evans already used `FoldList`.

Comment: I think/hope the answer is different enough though...

Comment: totally agree with you on this :-)

Answer (score 7):

Another approach using `Fold`:

```
With[{len = 6}, Map[Fold[RotateRight, Array[# - 1 &, len, 2], {#}] &, RotateRight@Range[len]]]
```

Another approach using `Nest`:

```
With[{len = 6}, Map[Nest[RotateRight, Array[# - 1 &, len, 2], #] &, RotateRight@Range[len]]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Since @bmf challenged us to get to 10:

```
With[
  {len = 5},
  MapIndexed[RotateRight[#1, #2 - 1] &, ConstantArray[Range[len], len]]]
```

Comment: Also a (+1) as the other answer. I think that this 10-fold answers challenge will become a theme for any list and/or array related question. All credits to @Nasser

Answer (score 6):

Is this sufficiently different?

```
With[
  {len=5},
  NestList[Mod[#-1,len,1]&,Range[len],len-1]]
```

Comment: For me it's sufficient

Answer (score 6):

Another silly option:

```
rotmat[n_] := Module[
  {r = Range[n]},
  ArrayReshape[
   FoldList[{r[[-#2[[1]] ;;]], r[[;; -#2[[2]]]]} &, r, 
    Partition[r, 2, 1]], {n, n}]
  ]
```

Comment: Nicely done and we are one step closer :-)

Answer (score 6):

Since @kglr used the [`ToeplitzMatrix`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToeplitzMatrix.html), I thought it'd be a good idea to use the [`HankelMatrix`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HankelMatrix.html). Well, it was not but I managed to get the following

```
idm[n_] := IdentityMatrix[n]
hm[n_] := LowerTriangularize[Reverse@HankelMatrix[Range@n] + 1, -1]
diag[n_] := 
 Diagonal[Map[Sort, 
     UpperTriangularize[Transpose@Reverse@HankelMatrix[n]], 1], #] & /@
   Range[n - 1]
aux[n_] := Table[diag[n][[xx]] - (xx - 1), {xx, 1, n - 1}]
last[n_] := PadRight[ArrayPad[PadLeft[aux[n]], {0, {1, 0}}], {n, n}]
res[n_] := idm[n] + hm[n] + last[n]
```

We can check

```
Grid@Partition[MatrixForm /@ Table[res[i], {i, 2, 13}], 3]
```

> [image: matgrid]